# NativeScript 5 Core JavaScript Android Side Loading Tabs not Disabling

Tags: nativescript

I’m using NativeScript 5 Core JS and want to disable Android tab side loading. The documentation says using androidTabsPosition="bottom" should do that, but it’s not. It also says that androidOffscreenTabLimit has been deprecated in ver. 5.

My use case is I change a local storage variable on one page and when I navigate to a different page I want to check for that new value.

After the initial load, none of my page events fire. Works fine on iOS, but not in Android. Thanks.

Comment: `androidTabsPosition` should do the trick as mentioned in the docs. Even if it's loaded lazily (keeping `androidTabsPosition` set to `top`), you should not loose your events. Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Here's the Playground Link: <https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=HJvkXj&v=2>

Comment: After the initial load, only the side loading events happen. More specifically, when I click on the Browse tab from the Search Page, I get the Home Page loaded, but not the Browse Page. I want to be able to use the onLoaded or onNavigatingTo functions on each page as I click the tabs. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it always preloads at least one tab as per the source code. In case of placing tabs at top, it preloads based on `androidOffscreenTabLimit`. May be docs has to more clear.

Comment: Is the only solution to leave the tabs at the top?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are depended on loaded event, you could use `selectedIndexChange` event on TabView to keep track of which page is being displayed.

Comment: I'll give that a try, thanks.